# find hex number in string then convert it to decimal

Tags: c#, regex

Lets say I am receiving multiple different strings like

```
"private var color:uint = 0xff000010"
"private var something:uint = 0xf2010"
"private var anotherNumber:int = 5435344"
```

I want to check if the string contains hex number and if there is one to replace it with its decimal value.
For the conversion I think this would be enough:

```
string hexToDecimal = int.Parse(color, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString();
```

But I am new to the regex expressions and its hard for me to do the whole algorithm for finding and then replacing the hex in easy way.

I would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** 
Here is another example of what it should be able to convert:

```
"private var color:uint = 0xff000010 0x00000ff \n0xffffff"
```

Comment: Can you use `str.Split().Last()` to get the relevant token?

Comment: How about splitting with `" = "` (without quotes) and take the second item and try to parse it?

Comment: What are the criteria for detecting the number? If there's a number after the = will it always be hex? Is it only numbers that start with 0x?

Comment: if tasks like this will be rather often - I recommend you to write an interpreter based on BNF grammar

Comment: Actually you don't know what you will receive.The point is only if you receive a hex number to replace it with decimal. The string may be `"asfdafasdf 0x04234"` for example

Comment: BTW, `5435344` can be parsed with `NumberStyles.HexNumber` as well. If you don't get a verifiable data, maybe you shouldn't _even_ try to parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Regex.Replace` overload with a Match evaluator (see [demo](http://ideone.com/DAXjcm)):

```
var s = "private var color:uint = 0xff000010\nprivate var something:uint = 0xf2010\nprivate var anotherNumber:int = 5435344";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?i)\b0x([a-f0-9]+)\b", m => Hex2Dec(m.Groups[1].Value));
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

The evaluator method is

```
public static string Hex2Dec(string m)
{
    return int.Parse(m, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString();
}
```

Output:

```
private var color:uint = -16777200
private var something:uint = 991248
private var anotherNumber:int = 5435344
```

The regex matches:

- `(?i)` - makes the pattern case-insensitive
- `\b` - word boundary
- `0x` - a literal sequence of `0x`
- `([a-f0-9]+)` - Group 1 matching one or more characters from `a-f` or `0-9` character ranges
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
        string input = "private var color:uint = 0xff000010";

        Match match = Regex.Match(input, @".*(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+).*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            string key = match.Groups[1].Value;

            uint hexToDecimal = (uint)new System.ComponentModel.UInt32Converter().ConvertFromString(key);
            input = input.Replace(key, hexToDecimal.ToString());          
        }
```

hex number is changed in input variable, if matched

Comment: it works for this case ,but lets say we have a string 
`"private var color:uint = 0xff000010 0x00000ff"`it will convert only 0x00000ff